# MVC 4 bundle and minification how turn it off?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do I turn off bundle and minification for production? Without using the debug=false..

I am having an issue where in dev my web page looks OK but in production it doesn't.  I just want to turn it off just to make sure that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it temporarily on the server is to set `debug` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your .aspx file:  `System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`