# Turning off bundling and minification (WEBFORMS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I have created a new asp.net website to test this feature. Now I want to be able to dynamically control whether bundling/ minification can be toggled at runtime. Most of the code was self generated as shown below except the line for turning off optimization.

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            // I ADDED THIS LINE ONLY TO TURN OFF OPTIMIZATION.
            System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
                            "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

            // Order is very important for these files to work, they have explicit dependencies
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

            // Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
                "respond",
                new ScriptResourceDefinition
                {
                    Path = "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
                    DebugPath = "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                });
        }
```

My questions are as follows:

1) I was under the impression that enableOptimization was supposed to turn off optimization and I would see unbundled scripts in the browser without having to modify my markup. I thought the scriptManager automatically handled this and pushed out the individual JS files when it sees above mentioned flag.

2) Having the debug to true in web.config would also trigger the enableoptimization to false.

Are both these assumptions false?

**EDIT**

1) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460199/mvc-4-bundle-and-minification-how-turn-it-off) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848452/turn-off-bundling-minification-while-debugging-in-webforms) are similar questions but no answers!

**EDIT 2**

```
public class OptimizationModule : IHttpModule
{

    private const string PARAM_NAME = "minify";


    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest +=(new EventHandler(this.context_BeginRequest));
    }



    private void context_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
        // request and response properties.

        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;         

        if (application != null && application.Request.QueryString[PARAM_NAME] != null)
        {
            bool minify;
            bool.TryParse(application.Request.QueryString[PARAM_NAME], out minify);

            if (!minify)
            {
                BundleTable.Bundles.Clear();
                BundleConfigs.GenerateBundles(BundleTable.Bundles, false);                    
            }
            else {
                BundleTable.Bundles.Clear();
                BundleConfigs.GenerateBundles(BundleTable.Bundles, true);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

I tried adding an httphandler to allow the luxury for changing the optimization while running the application. So I thought I would just pass something like this  : localhost/page.aspx?minify=false on client side just to view how the unminified version looks like, if I need to debug something. But this does not seem to change anything. So does it mean that whatever settings I have at the start would be continued throughout the session or can they be changed.

Comment: Hi Farax, have you rebuilt the project since disabling optimization ?

You actually have to rebuild it rather than run it, so right click solutions --> build project

I had the same problem and this solved it for me